# How to write /aperture in LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex

For example you can write `f / 1.1` or `\it{f}/1.1` on the LaTeX directive, for example,
Do you have any better suggestions; best results on LaTeX show /apertures how many.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `\it{f}/1.1` would make the `/1.1` and the rest of the document italic.

Comment: [wikipedia image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Lenses_with_different_apertures.jpg/330px-Lenses_with_different_apertures.jpg) suggests `$f/1.4$` should be fine.